# External Hard drive automount problem

Tags: snow-leopard, mac-mini, external-disk

I have a Drobo hooked up to my intel mac mini mounted to /Volumes/Drobo, although after a poweroutage the Drobo now automounts to /Volumes/Drobo 1.  I unmount it and mount it back on /Volumes/Drobo so that all of my apps work but, how can I force it to go back to using /Volumes/Drobo as the automount location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a folder named /Volumes/Drobo, so it has to pick a different name to mount the drive under.  In one sense, this is fairly easy to fix: just rename/move/delete that folder, remount the drive, and you're set.

But it's probably more complicated than that because you probably have something set to automatically access something in /Volumes/Drobo, and when that doesn't exist it'll recreate it (which is probably what caused the problem in the first place -- after the port failure, the Drobo didn't remount in time, and whatever it was created an empty folder where it should've been).  So, you'll need to figure out what's recreating that folder, and get it to stop long enough to do the rename and remount operation.